# Unable to upgrade to Android Studio 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using `Android Studio 1.4.1`.
When I manually try to upgrade Android Studio via

**File -> Settings -> Update**

I get the message:

> "You already have the latest version of Android Studio installed".

But there should already be 1.5.1 in the stable chanel. I also used all the others chanels but i get the same message all the time.

Comment: On which OS are you developping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download and install the latest version form the Android website: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Studio will detect settings from older versions and prompt you to import them on first run.

Answer (score 0):

As written on tools.android.com the best way to update it should be if you do it seperately.
"You can update your current 1.4 installation to 1.5 Preview 2 by using the built-in patch mechanism (make sure you switch to the Canary channel first, if necessary.)

BUT YOU MAY NOT WANT TO DO THAT. Patch-updating to this new version will replace your existing stable installation with a preview version. Instead, you can download a separate installation of 1.5 from the Android Studio 1.5 Preview 2 page. You can keep 1.4 and 1.5 installed side by side; they use separate settings and cache directories."

Comment: This information is outdated, 1.5 has been the stable release for some time.

Comment: Well, the OP wants to upgrade from the stable channel which means, 1.5.1 is available on `stable` channel and the OP should be able to downlaod it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.the solution is, perhaps that's because of your `Country's Ip` maybe it is blocked like iran ip's.

I have to change my ip to another country and then it should work and downloading the new version.

hope that helps.